# Convex subsets of infinite dimensional spaces up homeomorphism

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, frechet-manifold

Let $C$ be a convex, infinite-dimensional, non-locally-compact subset of a separable Frechet space.

If $C$ is a closed subset (or more generally, if $C$ is completely metrizable), then it is known that $C$ is homeomorphic to $\ell^2$, the separable Hilbert space. This is proved in [Separable complete ANR's admitting a group structure are Hilbert manifolds](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0166864181900018) by Dobrowolski and Toruńczyk.

In the non-completely-metrizable case, a topological classification of such $C$'s is (apparently) wide-open. I wish to have more examples of such $C$'s.
Do they belong to infinitely many homeomorphism types?

Comment: Let $B\subset C$ be the centrally symmetric open and closed unit balls in $\ell^2$. Do you mean in particular to classify topologically all sets $X$ such that $B\subseteq X\subseteq C$?

Comment: @WlodzimierzHolsztynski, at least I do not see why such a classification is impossible. As I mentioned, all $G_\delta$ (i.e. all completely metrizable) subsets are homeomorphic.